# Get size of all QStackedWidget items on application launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have made an application in PyQt5. I want my application to resize each of the elements of `QStackedWidget` the moment application is launched.

Currently, it resizes those elements(Pages herein) only when I visit those Pages one by one.

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, stacked_widget):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.stacked_widget = stacked_widget

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click here!')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.goto)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def goto(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)


class Page(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, stacked_widget, idx):
        super(Page, self).__init__()
        self.stacked_widget = stacked_widget
        self.idx = idx

        menu = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        menu.setText('Select Page')
        menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191); padding: 1px;")
        viewType = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        group = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(viewType)
        texts = ["Page 01", "Page 02", "Page 03"]
        for text in texts:
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(text, viewType)
            viewType.addAction(action)
            group.addAction(action)
        group.setExclusive(True)
        group.triggered.connect(self.onTriggered)
        menu.setMenu(viewType)
        menu.setPopupMode(QtWidgets.QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        viewType.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
        menu.setFixedWidth(90)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(menu)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def event(self, e):
        if e.type() in (QtCore.QEvent.Show, QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
            print("Page: {}, size".format(self.idx), self.width(), self.height())

        return QtWidgets.QWidget.event(self, e)

    def onTriggered(self, action):
            if action.text() == 'Page 01':
                self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)
            elif action.text() == 'Page 02':
                self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(2)
            elif action.text() == 'Page 03':
                self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(3)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        widget_1 = Main(self.stacked_widget)
        widget_2 = Page(self.stacked_widget, 1)
        widget_3 = Page(self.stacked_widget, 2)
        widget_4 = Page(self.stacked_widget, 3)

        wid_list = [widget_1, widget_2, widget_3, widget_4]

        for wid in wid_list:
            self.stacked_widget.addWidget(wid)

        self.showMaximized()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output should look like below the moment application is launched:

```
Page: 1, size 1920 986
Page: 1, size 1920 986
Page: 2, size 1920 986
Page: 2, size 1920 986
Page: 3, size 1920 986
Page: 3, size 1920 986
```

**Edit 1:**

I need this information at launch time because my actual project consists of video frames on these `Pages` and I have drawn some points/zones on these frames using `OpenCV`. In case I'm unable to resize them at launch time, they show a lot of *offset* at my Dashboard which is defined in `Main` class (I have just placed a QPushBtton in this example).

**Edit 2:**

I tried a work-around to this by modifying my `Main` class as below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from threading import Timer

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, stacked_widget):
        .........
        .........
        t = Timer(60.0, self.hello)
        t.start()

    def hello(self):
        for i in range(1,7):
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(i)
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

But then I get `QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread`. Though, the application works in this case but I know it's not the correct approach and I'm afraid it may cause problem in future.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need that information? Widgets in a stacked layout are always actually resized and mapped only when they are finally shown, this is pretty standard for any widget, which is only actually resized when it's shown (or a layout has to force the resizing).

Comment: @deepanshu About the edit2, don't use threading just a QTimer: `QTimer.singleShot(60 * 1000, self.hello)`

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thanks. that worked without any error or warnings. Could you please tell me if ```QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread``` have  caused my application to crash?

Comment: @deepanshu Basic rule in Qt: you **cannot** and **must not** modify (or create) the GUI from another thread directly as the GUI is not thread-safe. If to your application you mean the code that you have provided then that is the cause, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: @deepanshu it seems strange that you need to paint something *before* showing the widget (and, most importantly, before it's mapped), and I believe that if you need to do that it's probably due to a wrong approach. If you can better explain that need (and provide a practical example code) we might help you with that.

Comment: @musicamante, every word you said is correct. I don't paint anything before showing the widget. What actually happens is that the application is supposed to run 24x7 at clients side. And we don't face any issue while painting/drawing anything on the widgets (because they get mapped at that time). *The problem occurs when we have to restart the application in case it stops for any xyz reason*. Because then the widgets are not resized and mapped accordingly and we see an offset.

Comment: According to what you indicate you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), instead of asking about your underlying problem (objective) you ask for a possible solution that no one guarantees is correct. By having an XY problem you limit you solve them, and perhaps there is a correct or better solution to the one you are trying.

Comment: @eyllanesc, by *xyz reason*, I meant a possible hardware issue, a power breakdown or something like that which has nothing to do with the application itself.